# How to insert new slide with < > tag

Tags: beamer, slideshow

I am new to beamer. Here in this case `<7->` is not creating new slides rather that `<6->` prints the ABC5 and ABCBLOCK together. What is the possible solution if I want separate slides for ABC5 and ABCBLOCK. And also in place of `<7->` there is a weird sign which I can't explain what it is.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{utopia} 



\title[abc]{Abc}
\author{M.X\inst{1}}
\institute{
    \inst{1}
        Department Of CSE\\
        X University
}

\date{20 June, 2017}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    <1->
 \frametitle{Examples}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item <2-> ABC1.
        \item <3-> ABC2
        \item <4-> ABC3
        \item <5-> ABC4
        \item <6-> ABC5
        <7->        
        \begin{block}{Disclaimer}
             ABCBLOCK
        \end{block} 
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: How things are named is a bit counter intuitive when you starts with `beamer`, but you should have a look to the user guide to understand the difference between *slides* (linked to a "page number") and *frames* (linked to a "pdf page"). You also have tutorials that are really informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is due to the `<7->` that should be positioned right after `\begin{block}`. 
For more details, see [`beamer` user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) on section 9.4 *Environments with Overlay Specifications*. In Section 12.3 *Block environment*, it is also stated that the correct syntax for block environments is:

> ```
> \begin{block}<⟨action specification⟩>{⟨block title⟩}<⟨action specification⟩>
> ⟨environment contents⟩
> \end{block}
> ```

---

You should thus modify your code as following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Examples}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item <2-> 2
            \item <3-> 3
            \item <4-> 4
            \item <5-> 5
            \item <6-> 6        
            \begin{block}<7->{Disclaimer}%<------- look here!
                 7
            \end{block} 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works like a charm and I understand the concept of writing < -> syntax

Comment: @Maruf Glad to help you!